# Android-apply patch on media codec sample

Tags: android, patch, android-mediacodec

i about a a week that i am chasing my tail to run some of the examples here(media coec examples): http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/

some of them are build for CTS but can implement with some changes.
I hope that i am not the only one who deal with it.

I want to ask about this patch:"Android Breakout game recorder patch "

I already loaded to game project to eclipse and can run it on my device.
But when i apply the patch through "Team->apply patch" in eclise.
the patch was apply but with error of "missing files" on some of the changes.

Is anybody can help me to apply it  well?

There is not git working examples yet with media codec. and any help with the setup will be great.

Many Thanks for any answer!

**update** : please,NEVER use cynogenMod ROM for new API development. I could not run many classes with their 4.3.1(API 18).after switch to official all run as expected

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're building for API 18 -- part of the patch updates `android:minSdkVersion` in the manifest. The best way to apply the patch is to download the Breakout sources with git, save the patch in the top directory, and use `git am <patchfile>` to apply the patch with git.  (The patch file was created with `git format-patch`.)

FWIW, if you want to see simultaneous screen rendering and recording in action, the "Show + capture camera" feature of [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika/) also does this. That's also juggling the camera, and trying to keep the video encoder running across activity restarts and device sleeps, so the code is a little more complex.  As with the Breakout patch, it operates by rendering the same scene twice, to two different surfaces.

Grafika includes a TextureView-based video player -- select `camera-test.mp4` to play back the video.

Comment: when try to run Grafika i get  progress bar that stuck in the middle of "preparing content of gen-eight-rect.mp4
in the log i get this : 12-22 00:53:23.615: D/Grafika(27529): Can't find readable /data/data/com.android.grafika/files/gen-sliders.mp4
12-22 00:53:23.725: D/Grafika(27529): doInBackground...

Comment: seems like it cant generate  to 8 rect video from the bigflake sample. it happened to me with the EncodeAndMuxTest.java until i change something there.but im not sure how to do it there.i don't interesting in decode,so maybe i can skip it somehow?i just cant cancel this progress bar from the app

Comment: starnge-im running it on cynogen mod 4.3.1-it mean 18.i set the min sdk and target to 18-and still get  "device driver api 17". is the cynogen mod or i didnt set somthing?the code compile and running.very strange

Comment: Grafika generates two movies (gen-eight-rects and gen-sliders) into the app's file directory if they don't already exist.  Getting stuck is not expected.  I haven't tried a cyanogenmod device before.  You can work around the problem by creating a couple of dummy files by hand on the device... but if simple movie generation isn't working, I'm not sure how much else will work either.

Comment: i succeeded to apply the patch.now i get 11 sec video with 68 frames only,very far from the 30 FPS.look really slow.any idea why? it is 1280X720 video of course. more then that,the game is really slow too now,as opposite to the pre patch game.maybe the game is the source for that?but before path it work really fast.

Comment: What device are you using?  With a Nexus 4 I was able to get full speed.  Recording the video at a lower resolution may help.  On some devices you'll get better results if you play the game -- some battery-conservation strategies involve dropping the CPU/GPU frequencies if the user isn't interacting with the device, so if you aren't touching the screen regularly everything slows down.  (Breakout used to be sluggish on N4 if you selected "never lose ball" and just watched; that's what inspired the update to Breakout 1.2.)

Comment: FWIW, if you want to dig into it you can try to use systrace (http://bigflake.com/systrace/) to try to figure out where the performance issues are.  The Breakout patch adds `android.os.Trace` calls to the app itself (enable with `--app=com.faddensoft.breakout` when running systrace) which can be helpful in determining where the time is being spent.  systrace is disabled on some devices.

Comment: Hi,im using galaxy s3.ill try to use the systrace even thought it look a bit complex to me.i will make some more test manually at least.many Thanks again Fadden:)

Comment: really "ZERO" debugging efforts -but when i switch to 640X480 from 1280X720- the FPS increase from 6 to 16.(breakout game recording). is that bad news?